# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input in vitest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, vite, vitest

I am getting this error while generating coverage with vitest in react

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
 ❯ new Converter node_modules/v8-to-istanbul/node_modules/convert-source-map/index.js:83:15
 ❯ exports.fromComment node_modules/v8-to-istanbul/node_modules/convert-source-map/index.js:181:10
 ❯ exports.fromSource node_modules/v8-to-istanbul/node_modules/convert-source-map/index.js:207:22
 ❯ V8ToIstanbul.load node_modules/v8-to-istanbul/lib/v8-to-istanbul.js:53:24
 ❯ node_modules/@vitest/coverage-v8/dist/provider.js:392:25
 ❯ V8CoverageProvider.convertCoverage node_modules/@vitest/coverage-v8/dist/provider.js:388:7
 ❯ V8CoverageProvider.reportCoverage node_modules/@vitest/coverage-v8/dist/provider.js:273:25
 ❯ Vitest.reportCoverage node_modules/vitest/dist/vendor/node.d5m7SYoI.js:8339:7
```

Here's a vitest config file:

```js
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [viteTsconfigPaths()],
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: 'jsdom',
    setupFiles: './src/setup-tests.ts',
    include: ['src/**/*.test.ts', 'src/**/*.test.tsx'],
    exclude: [...configDefaults.exclude, '*.js'],
    coverage: {
      provider: 'v8',
      reporter: ['lcov', 'text'],
    },
    outputFile: 'coverage/sonar-report.xml',
  },
});
```

Comment: I got one lead. It's happening at this line in convert-source-map package.
`if (opts.isJSON || opts.encoding) {
    sm = JSON.parse(sm);
  }`
sm is empty in this case